# R: how to identify the minimum representative vector/row sets from a list of vectors/dataframe

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors each contains a number of elements. I would like to identify the minimum number of vectors that have the maximum coverage of unique elements. For example, if the vectors are represented as row in binary dataframe with the unique elements in columns, as follows:

```
    >df<- data.frame(a=c(1,0,0,0,0),b=c(1,1,1,1,0),c=c(1,0,1,1,1),d=c(0,0,0,1,1),e=c(0,0,0,1,1), f=c(0,0,0,0,1))
    > df
        a b c d e f
      1 1 1 1 0 0 0
      2 0 1 0 0 0 0
      3 0 1 1 0 0 0
      4 0 1 1 1 1 0
      5 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Given that the vectors are the rows from 1 to 5 and they contain different combinations of the elements a to f. I would like to get the minimum representative vectors or rows covering as many elements. In this example, the minimum representative (maximum parsimonious) vectors are rows 1 and 5. Is there a way to do that statistically? I tried to visualize the dataset in the two-way clustered heatmap to manually identify the minimum combinations. however, is there a statistical approach that can handle this and capable of providing some numeric measure of the selection performance?

Another example to illustrate my question. Given the following vectors:

```
    > vec.1 <- c("a", "c", "d")
    > vec.2 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
    > vec.3 <- c("b","e")
    > vec.4 <- c("b", "c", "d", "g")
    > vec.5 <- c("f","g")
```

The minimum combination is 2,3 and 5 because they cover all elements, from a to g, with minimum overlap. In larger datasets, multiple answers can be possible, however, the smaller the number of vectors in a combination the better.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you need `i1 <- apply(df, 1, FUN = function(x) length(rle(x)$values));df[i1,]`

Comment: It is a combinatorical problem. First: is there one row with all 1? If not second: is there a combination of two rows which covers all elements. If not: ... three ... Use the function `combn()` to generate the combinations. If a combination is found calculate the amount of overlap to select the comination with minimal overlap.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to compute 'overlaps' between rows and extract the row pair with maximum overlap as follows:

```
m <- apply(df, 1, function(x) apply(df, 1, function(y) sum(x | y)))
which(m == max(m), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

The resulting output is:

```
     row col
[1,]   5   1
[2,]   1   5
```

You can pick either combination (since row 1 vs. row 5 and row 5 vs. row 1 are same).

This method uses n^2 operations though. Not sure if there is a more efficient package/algorithm that finds maximum hamming distance pairs of rows, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Hi Gopala, thank you so much for your reply. I have tried this in my data set and it gives me the pairs with maximum coverage. Is there a way to get the combination of maximum coverage, i.e.  2 rows or more. The idea to represent all the data in as minimum number of rows as possible. So, if I understand your approach correctly, overlap should be tested on all possible combination of rows.

Comment: There will be computationally prohibitive combinations to test. Don't see how that will work.

Answer (score 0):

It is a combinatorical problem. First: is there one row with all 1? If not second: is there a combination of two rows which covers all elements. If not: ... three ... Use the function `combn()` to generate the combinations. If a combination is found calculate the amount of overlap to select the comination with minimal overlap:

```
df<- data.frame(a=c(1,0,0,0,0),b=c(1,1,1,1,0),c=c(1,0,1,1,1),d=c(0,0,0,1,1),e=c(0,0,0,1,1), f=c(0,0,0,0,1))
n <- nrow(df)
test1.allc <- function(i) all(colSums(df[i,, drop=FALSE])>0)
for (i in 1:n) {
  Ci <- combn(n,i)
  t1 <- apply(Ci, 2, test1.allc)
  if (any(t1)) break # minimal number of rows/vectors is i
}
print(i) # number of rows needed to have all elements
Ci <- Ci[, t1, drop=FALSE] # only valid combinations

overlap <- function(j) { o <- colSums(df[j,, drop=FALSE]); sum(o) - length(o) }
j <- which.min(apply(Ci, 2, overlap))
print(j) # the j-th combination(s) has/have minimal overlap
for (jj in j) print(df[Ci[, jj],])
```

Comment: Hi jogo. Thank you for your response. I have tried it and it gives me this error: Error in base::colSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions.

Comment: @Samar.y You used other data? For the given data the code gave the right result. I edited my answer to be more robust.